# Finger Counting Problem to find the name of the finger based on the given number

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

A boy starts counting using her left hand’s fingers. The counting sequence is like 1-thumb, 2-index finger, 3-middle finger, 4-ring finger, 5-little finger then in the reverse order like 6-ring finger, 7-middle  finger, 8-index  finger, 9 thumb. Then again 10-index finger and so on. The program must print the last finger used for counting for a given value of N. The fingers names are thumb, index, middle, ring and little.

I found the answer for thumb finger, index finger and the little finger. But I couldnt find the patter for the index and the ring finger. below is the code that i have tried.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Your Code Here
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        long n=sc.nextInt();
        
        if(n%8 == 1) System.out.print("thumb");
        else if(n%8 == 5) System.out.print("little");
        else if(n%4 == 3) System.out.print("middle");
        else {
          // logic for index and ring finger.
        }

    }
}
```

someone please help me to finish the logic.

Comment: You might need to use the `||` ("or") operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by *[@dawood-ibn-kareem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081110/dawood-ibn-kareem)* to use `||`; you can use it something like:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n = sc.nextInt();
        
        if (n % 8 == 1) {
            System.out.print("thumb");
        } else if (n % 8 == 5) {
            System.out.print("little");
        } else if (n % 4 == 3) {
            System.out.print("middle");
        } else if (n % 8 == 2 || n % 8 == 0) {
            System.out.print("index");
        } else if (n % 8 == 4 || n % 8 == 6) {
            System.out.print("ring");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Giving complete solutions to obvious homework problems is generally not encouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thanks. Will keep this in mind going forward

Answer (score 2):

This should just be some `if-else` logic with the `||` operator. You can use an array of strings to make the code even more concise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see @dawood-ibn-kareem's comment, but here's way of thinking about it. Suppose the hand has 9 fingers, denoted:

- T for thumb
- L for little finger
- IF for index finger when counting from T to L
- IB for index finger when counting from L to T
- MF for middle finger when counting from T to L
- MB for middle finger when counting from L to T
- RF for ring finger when counting from T to L
- RB for ring finger when counting from L to T

Then the counts landing on each finger are as follows.

- T:  1,  9, 17, 25,... or n when n % 8 = 1
- IF: 2, 10, 18, 26,... or n when n % 8 = 2
- MF: 3, 11, 19, 27,... or n when n % 8 = 3
- RF: 4, 12, 20, 28,... or n when n % 8 = 4
- L:  5, 13, 21, 29,... or n when n % 8 = 5
- RB: 6, 14, 22, 30,... or n when n % 8 = 6
- MB: 7, 15, 23, 31,... or n when n % 8 = 7
- IB: 8, 16, 24, 32,... or n when n % 8 = 0

We could then construct a hashmap (sorry, I don't know Java) to map `n % 8` to the finger landed upon:

```
{ 0 = I, 1 = T, 2 = I, 3 = M, 4 = R, 5 = L, 6 = R, 7 = M }
```

If this hashmap were `hash_map`, one could identify the finger when, for example, `n = 322`:

```
hash_map.get(322 % 8) #=> hash_map.get(2) #=> 'I'
```